# Why does float data type gives weird output when casted with large numbers

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to understand the behavior of large numbers when casted with Float Data type in spark.

[image]

Last select statement in the above picture gives very abrupt output.

Thanks in Advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output is not abrupt. It is simply a demonstration of the limitation of the truncated floating-point representation. `FloatType` in Spark is backed by Java's `float` - [32-bit IEEE754 floating-point number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format). It has 24 bits for the significand, but the MSB is always `1` and hence the actual precision is only 23 bits.

123456789.6 is 1.8396495223045348... x 2<sup>26</sup>. 1.8396495223045348 is 1.110101101111001101000101011001... in binary. Limiting it to only 24 bits results in 1.11010110111100110100011 (the last bit is rounded up), which is 1.8396495580673218 in decimal. Multiply it by 2<sup>26</sup> and you get 123456792.